# output of map task written to local file system or HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I read that the Hadoop Map tasks write their output to local disk.

Suppose if i have map only tasks without any reducers, still the map outputs will be written to local file system ?

Comment: If you found Ravi's answer helpful, mark is as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will still write the output to the path set by FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(JobConf, Path) and there will no sorting or partitioning.

[More info:](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf.html#ReducerNone)

UPDATE: As mentioned by Chris White, it will be written directly to HDFS and not the local file system.

Comment: To clarify, no they will not be written to local file system, but instead will be written directly to HDFS.